# Robot - AutoClicking while holding down left click

Tags: java, mouseevent, awtrobot

Is there a way to make the robot auto click for you if you hold down left click and then stop when you release? This is what I currently have... Which doesn't work.

```
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    if (!disable) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            if (!randomCPS) {
                robotClick(cps, typeOfClick);
            } else if (randomCPS) {
                robotRandomizedBetweenClicks(fromCPS, toCPS, typeOfClick);
            }
        }
    }
}


public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        disable = true;
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your ```main``` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a boolean named clicking. In your mousePressed method, set clicking to true, and in mouseReleased set it to false.

```
private boolean clicking = false;
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {
   clicking = true;
      if (!disable) {
         if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            if (!randomCPS) {
              robotClick(cps, typeOfClick);
              } else if (randomCPS) {
            robotRandomizedBetweenClicks(fromCPS, toCPS, typeOfClick);
            }
       }
    }
 }


public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {
  clicking = false;
  if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
    disable = true;
    running = false;
}
}
```

That way, for the duration of your mouse press you can call whichever function you wish to use, and stop it the moment you release the button. If this means the function is being called too frequently, you can implement a counter to activate the function every fifth time it is called (or more).

Comment: Got it working, had to play around a bit, but got it working. Sorry for the late reply as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to constantly click/follow a path, essentially like drawing a line in MS Paint for example, then consider using a 'mouseDrag' or 'MouseClick'.

Have your JPanel extend `MouseMotionListener` & `MouseListener`

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) //try mouseDragged or the other methods which you're able to override once you've extended the classes I've mentioned above.
{       
    if (!randomCPS) 
    {
        robotClick(cps, typeOfClick);
    } 
    else if (randomCPS)
    {
        robotRandomizedBetweenClicks(fromCPS, toCPS, typeOfClick);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) 
{
    disable = true;
    running = false;
}
```